# Passing Pameters into ActionResult function in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

The basic idea of my program is as follows: I have a webpage that runs a C# program after the user gives some input. This C# program outputs a string that then will be displayed on a different webpage. In short, I just want to pass this string from one webpage to another, and then print it to the page. Yet it's proving to be very difficult. Here is my current attempt:

```
private ActionResult CallProgram(string path)
    {
        //some code from calling my C# program
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.FileName = @"\\WMRILTriageTool\Triage\callRunEXE\callRunEXE.exe";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = "-f " + path + " -d 0 -w 1";

        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            output = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //output saved to string
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();   
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Result?results=output"); //pass output to ActionResult
    }
```

This ActionResult function then gets called:

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Result(string results)
    {

        ViewBag.Message = "Results";
        ViewBag.toWrite = results;

        return View();
    }
```

As you can see I've tried using a query string, but this does not work. I get the error:

"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)"

To fix this I've tried putting the following into Web.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

But it does not work (still get the same error). So to summarize, how do I pass my string from my CallProgram function to an ActionResult function and then to another webpage? This seemingly simple procedure has taken me longer than I care to admit. Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues that I see here.  First off, I don't see how your could ever get the error you are getting.  This line of code:

```
return RedirectToAction("Result?results=output")
```

Will redirect to the same hardcoded location every time (`Result?results=output`).  I suspect you think you are doing something more like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Result?results=" + output)
```

Which could potentially generate the error you are talking about depending on the return value of `exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`

I would also say that keeping the config changes you have made would be a **huge** mistake.  These are safe guards built into .NET to prevent malicious users from hacking your site.  If you remove them without fully understanding what you are doing, it is likely that you will get into trouble.

If you show the string you are trying to pass in the query string we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Yes, I realized that changing web.config in such a way was a bad idea. Which is why I'm trying to avoid it. When I try: return RedirectToAction("Result?results=" + output) I get a "bad path" error.  The string that output is equal to is several hundred lines long, and I can't really show it here because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using url to pass data you should think about using a viewmodel class that shares information between the pages. It is much safer than your current way.

You might want to check this [msdn tutoria](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)l.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the output as URL will have lot of limitations. There is a limit on the number of char you can send in the URL as querystring and in case you want to send them in URL it is better to do the URLEncode / URLDecode so that you do not get any issue. The best way of passing the value to another result will be using the Viewmodel class. For example

```
             public class Result
            {
               public string Output;
            }
```

and pass the result instance to result action. One more way i can suggest is using the **TempData** , which is specifically meant for one this kind of case of just redirection . 
TempData is like ViewData, except that it persists for two successive requests making it useful for things like passing data between two different controller actions

Comment: Okay I've looked into the ViewModel class.How exactly is the above code an example of ViewModel? Isn't there a special declaration? I'll try to use TempData then. Can you explain a bit more how I should use it? Does it work as a global variable that I can access from any page of do I need to pass in through my ActionResult function to the new webpage directly? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GrantBall TempData is available after one request redirect , in next page you can check for TempData["key"] != null and then use it.